# I cannot @Spy Object in Cucumber Spring Boot Test in two Steps Definitions

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm having a problem running cucumber test with Spring Boot 2.

I have two steps definitions and in both clases I try to spy an object with 
mockito trying to capture the argument passed to one method of this class.

The point is that since Cucumber only allows one Spring Application Context Configuration I've created an abstract class to configure it and I've extended one of the steps definition with this class.

```
@ActiveProfiles("INTEGRATION_TEST")
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = 
      {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml"})
public abstract class BaseTestIntegration {}


@Ignore
public class OfferEventsGenerationStep extends BaseTestIntegration {

@Autowired private LoanOfferBatchController loanOfferBatchController;
@SpyBean private SendEventOfferServiceImpl sendEventService;
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<CreateOfferToUserEvent> createOfferEventCaptor;
@Autowired private GenericWebApplicationContext context;
.........
 @Then("^events will be created$")
public void eventsWillBeCreated() throws Throwable {
    Mockito.verify(sendEventService, Mockito.times(5)).sendEvent(createOfferEventCaptor.capture());
 }
}


@Ignore
public class SecondEventsGenerationStep  {

@Autowired private LoanOfferBatchController loanOfferBatchController;
@SpyBean private SendEventSencondServiceImpl sendEventService;
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<CreateOfferToUserEvent> createOfferEventCaptor;
@Autowired private GenericWebApplicationContext context;
.........
 @Then("^events will be created$")
public void eventsWillBeCreated() throws Throwable {
    Mockito.verify(sendEventService, Mockito.times(2)).sendEvent(createOfferEventCaptor.capture());
 }
}
```

And everything works fine except that sendEventService is only recognized as a spy bean in the class that extends the BaseTestIntegration class the other one throws this exception:

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
 Argument passed to verify() is of type SendEventSencondServiceImpl and is not a mock!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible to use `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` because `cucumber-spring` turns step definitions into beans and does not use the `TestContextManager`. There is an issue to [Support @MockBean in cucumber-spring #1470](http://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1470). It's up for grabs if anybody wants to take it.

Comment: As a work around I've joined these two step definitions in only one because SpyBean definitions needs to stay marked with SpringBootTest tag as you said on the issue thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'am facing on this issue. I used the solution below (waiting for a best idea) :

I replace my bean by the spy bean created via Mockito :

YourInstanceYourWantSpy spyingInstance=  Mockito.spy(YourInstanceYourWantSpy);

Then i use ReflectionUtils to replace the instance where it called.